# Sql Select Time Stamp and Represent it as 9 Hours Back

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day. I have a table that is collecting data in Universal Time Coordinated timestamps. However, the location is 9 hours back from this time. I am writing a query that gets the time-stamp and the value but 'casts' the timestamp 9 hours back since thats when it got recorded with respect to that location.

My issue is that I keep subtracting days not hours even though I specified hours in my 'datediff' and 'dateadd'. How do I select a timestamp and the value but represent that timestamp as 9 hours back? Thanks for any help.

```
select DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour,9,TimeUTC),0) as DateActual, Value
From TableData
```

Data

```
2015-12-15 00:00:00  45
2015-12-15 00:00:00  54
```

Current results

```
2015-12-06 00:00:00  45
2015-12-06 00:00:00  54
```

Desired results

```
2015-12-14 15:00:00  45
2015-12-14 15:00:00  54
```

Comment: The second argument of `DATEDIFF` should be a datetime value, not an integer. If you just want to subtract 9 hours, why isn't that expression just `DATEADD(HOUR, -9, TimeUTC) AS DateActual`?

Comment: @Dan no, what's happening is that is becoming `DATEDIFF(HOUR, '1900-01-10', TimeUTC)`... changing it to -9 would make it `DATEDIFF(HOUR, '1899-12-23', TimeUTC)`.

Comment: @Aaron, Dateadd(hour, -9, timeutc) worked perfect. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to consider storing your datetimes as datetimeoffset, which will allow you to store the time zone information as well.